# Is it possible to toggle between different qlik sense themes to make Apps more colorblind friendly?

Tags: themes, toggle, qliksense, color-blindness

We have  a number of colorblind users of our Qlik applications so I want to make them more accessible. I am seeking the easiest way to be able to toggle between colors that are colorblind friendly v ones that are meaningful to non colorblind users. Anyone know the most efficient way to do this?

I found this post, but it appears this might not be the recommended way to do this. Additionally, I can only get it half working. No matter what I put after the '/' it always changes to the same theme.

https://community.qlik.com/t5/App-Development/Toggle-Between-Themes-in-App/td-p/1737767

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme URL parameter is indeed the way to handle this, the trick is to use the theme `qextFilename` in the URL.

For example, I have a custom theme I use called **Arc theme**. I wouldn't use `/theme/Arc theme` in the URL, though, I would instead use the theme's `qextFilename` value which is `arc-theme`. So `/theme/arc-theme` will work correctly.

To find the `qextFilename` value:

- **Qlik Cloud**: In the Management Console, go to the Themes section and then find the `qextFilename` value for the desired theme in the table:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Cloud Management Console themes]

- **Qlik Sense Client Managed**: From the QMC, go to the Extensions section, find the desired theme, export it, and then check the name of the `qext` file:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense theme QEXT filename]

Comment: Exactly what I was stuck on-this is perfect, thank you!